# How can I make a reusable "CheckAll" checkbox solution in Vue2

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to create a reusable "Check All" solution for displaying a list of objects retrieved from an API.

I really like the get/set methods of computed properties that I use in this example here, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aLeLOZ but I find that rewriting the same function over and over again and maintaining a seperate checkbox state list is tedious.

index.html

```
<div id="app">

  <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectAll1"> Check All
  <div v-for="person in list1">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkbox" :value="person.id">
    <span>{{ person.name }}</span>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectAll2"> Check All
  <div v-for="person in list2">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkbox2" :value="person.id">
    <span>{{ person.name }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      list1: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Jenna1'},
        { id: 2, name: 'Jenna2'},
        { id: 3, name: 'Jenna3'},
        { id: 4, name: 'Jenna4'}
      ],
      list2: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Mary1'},
        { id: 2, name: 'Mary2'},
        { id: 3, name: 'Mary3'},
        { id: 4, name: 'Mary4'}
      ],
      checkbox: [],
      checkbox2: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    selectAll1: {
        get: function () {
          return this.list1 ? this.checkbox.length === this.list1.length : false
        },
        set: function (value) {
          let selected = []

          if (value) {
            this.list1.forEach(function (bf) {
              selected.push(bf.id)
            })
          }

          this.checkbox = selected
        }
      },
    selectAll2: {
        get: function () {
          return this.list2 ? this.checkbox2.length === this.list2.length : false
        },
        set: function (value) {
          let selected = []

          if (value) {
            this.list2.forEach(function (bf) {
              selected.push(bf.id)
            })
          }

          this.checkbox2 = selected
        }
      },
  }
});
```

How can I make a resuable selectAll() function that will work in this example that can be included as often as needed?

Is it possible to make a class that can maintain the check box state for each list and still function as a computed property to make use of the v-model directive?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same at all, but a method based solution would be

```
methods: {
  selectUs: function(){
    if (this.checkbox.length <= this.list1.length) {
      this.checkbox = Array.from(Array(this.list1.length + 1).keys())
    } else {
      this.checkbox = []
    }
  }
}
```

with @click="selectUs" instead of v-model="selectAll1"

(you could keep the `get` part of your computed properties to keep track of whether all are selected, and then use if (selectAll1) { etc } in the method)

Comment: My main requirement is to reuse the selectUs function for many different lists so I shouldn't be restricting the implementation.  This is a good solution as well, but how would I make it reusable?

Comment: check out this revised pen - basically, you pass the list and checkbox attributes of the component into the input at the same time you pass the @click 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrgpLy